# Global Statistics for Browser + Operating System

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to determine global statistics (similar to [StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/)'s) for a combination of Browser + OS.  For example, 35% (or whatever) of users are on XP **and** IE8.  StatCounter only displays one or the other (ex. 47.32% on XP, 30.20% on IE8).

Is anyone aware of a site that offers this information - preferably free of charge - or a way to glean it from StatCounter or others?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need to know what OS people are using? In terms of websites, the OS they're on is almost meaningless.

Comment: I'm mostly curious to know how many XP users are using a flavor of IE. Given that XP is 47.32% of the internet, and IE9 is only for Vista/Win7, I'm curious to know what percentage of the overall internet population will be using a non-HTML5/CSS3 compliant browser for the foreseeable future. Simply knowing the number of IE8 users doesn't tell me anything as those are spread between XP, Vista and Win7 - some of whom will be upgrading.

Comment: who says they won't just upgrade from xp as well though?

Comment: Eventually I have no doubt that everyone will upgrade from XP. But I'm making the assumption that anyone using XP and an IE flavour is either a corporate user who has no control over their desktop environment, or a non-technical user who doesn't know any better than using IE. In both of these cases the upgrade path/timeframe to Win7 could be quite far off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.statowl.com is the closest thing to a free source of this sort of information, that I've been able to find. For example, [here's a chart](http://www.statowl.com/operating_system_market_share_by_os_version.php?timeframe=last_6&interval=month&chart_id=4&limit%5B%5D=windows&limit%5B%5D=mac&limit%5B%5D=linux&fltr_br=Safari&fltr_se=&fltr_cn=) showing the percentage of Safari users by operating system.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with statowl's interface, but would it be fair to say that http://www.statowl.com/operating_system_market_share_by_os_version.php?timeframe=last_6&interval=month&chart_id=4&limit%5B%5D=windows&limit%5B%5D=mac&limit%5B%5D=linux&fltr_br=Internet+Explorer&fltr_se=&fltr_cn= is saying that 50% of IE users are on XP? And http://www.statowl.com/web_browser_market_share.php indicates that 61% of internet users are on IE, so effectively 30% of the internet is on both XP and IE? Or is my logic flawed somewhere.

Comment: I think your inference is correct (except insofar as StatOwl's figures aren't for the whole internet, just a large but mostly US-based sample set: http://www.statowl.com/about_our_data.php). At least, I hope so, because since I found StatOwl, I've been using its figures to make the same sort of calculations. One thing I haven't been able to do from StatOwl's figures is directly infer, for instance, the relative popularity of different *versions* of IE among that 30%. The closest I can get is to assume the distribution mirrors the distribution for Windows overall: http://is.gd/JwhwJ9

Comment: Ya, I hear what you're saying about versions, but since I'm primarily concerned about IE9+ (or IE8- as the case may be), it comes down to OS. I realize you opened a bounty on this, but your answer is definitely the closest to what I was looking for, so I guess the bounty is yours :)

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering this same thing due to the fact that IE on XP cannot do SNI SSL.  Thanks for answering.

To save someone 15 minutes of digging + math on statowl.com, here's what I found
IE users are 50% of browser users
30% of IE users use XP.
Therefore, 15% of the US-based internet is using IE on XP as of Nov 2012